# Way to pass argument to template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

Lets assume I have a template function

```
template <typename T>
void do_sth(T const&);
```

For some types ("small" and copyable) it would be better to pass an argument by value instead of reference.

So my question is: What is the simplest way to overload a function depending on the underlying type?

Remark:
Best what I came to is using `enable_if` with some conditions of "simple" type. And I believe there's no such a type trait as "simple type" in the standard library. Correct me if I'm wrong. Moreover: Using `enable_if` gets complicated as a function takes more template arguments (**edited**) because `template <typename T, typename U> void do_sth(T, U)` would need 4 overloads: (value, value), (value, ref), (ref, value) and (ref, ref).

Comment: Are you looking for `std::is_pod` ?

Comment: "Moreover: Using enable_if gets complicated as a function takes more template arguments." - not necessarily: you can apply `std::enable_if` to the return type: `template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<someTestOver<T>> do_sth (T const &);`

Comment: "small" is subjective, I would say, you might combine `sizeof+`is_pod` or similar.

Comment: maybe `std::is_trivially_copyable` instead of `std::is_pod`? `std::is_pod` is deprecated in C++20

Comment: Also: Maybe your function is simple enough that the compiler inlines the call anyways and can factor out the reference?

Comment: While all the above is correct, for any real application - if it isn't showing up as the bottleneck in your tight loop, don't prematurely optimize this code. Leave it as is.

Comment: @max66 I thought about a function that takes more template arguements `template <typename T, typename U> void do_str(T, U)` - to achieve what I've been looking for one would need 4 variants: (value, value), (value, ref), (ref, value), (ref, ref).

Answer (score 0):

boost has [call_traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm):

```
template <typename T>
void do_sth(typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type)
```

But one big issue is that `T` is no longer deducible
(and so you have to call it `do_sth<int>(42)` or `do_sth<MyBigObj>(myBigObj)`).

So might be used for non template methods in template class:

```
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    void do_sth(typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type);
};
```

But anyway, chances are that compiler actually inlines code, resulting in same generated code.

Comment: I think I'm looking for something like the first example but something that works:) Actually trying to use `boost::call_traits` is what I started from (and failed:))

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.  Template functions are inlined at the drop of a hat, and a reference to an x is an alias with no identity once the function is inlined.

Encourage the function to be inlined instead of doing a mess of SFINAE, unless and until you have proven this to be an important bottleneck.

After discovering this function is taking up more time than anything else you can optimize, test its improvement by manualy writing the by value version in a couple of key cases to ensure you actually get a benefit (I doubt you will).

Comment: You are probably right. Probably my question is an academic one. But I wondered if there is an elegant and simple solution to achieve it. Anyway - not all functions are inlined.